# ImportError: cannot import name 'strftime'

Tags: datetime, python-3.x

I am getting an error and not sure why, my code is as follows:

```
year1 = int(input('choose a year :',))
month1 = int(input('choose a month :',))
day1 = int(input('choose a day :',))
year2 = int(input('choose a year :',))
month2 = int(input('choose a month :',))
day2 = int(input('choose a day :',))
from datetime import date, timedelta as td
from datetime import strftime as st
d1 = date(year1, month1, day1)
d2 = date(year2, month2, day2)
delta = d2 - d1
for i in range(delta.days + 1):
day = st((d1 + td(days=i)))
print(get_exrates(day))
```

the full error code i get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    line 17, in <module>
    from datetime import strftime as st
ImportError: cannot import name 'strftime'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) is an instance method of `datetime` class You need to import `datetime` from `datetime` module first then use its `strftime` method :

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strftime
<method 'strftime' of 'datetime.date' objects>
```

Comment: `from datetime import date, timedelta as td
from datetime import strftime as st
from datetime import datetime
d1 = date(year1, month1, day1)
d2 = date(year2, month2, day2)
delta = d2 - d1
for i in range(delta.days + 1):
day = datetime.st((d1 + td(days=i)))
print(get_exrates(day))`

Brings up another error 

TypeError: Required argument 'format' (pos 1) not found

Comment: @StevenGhandi whats the problem?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
     day = datetime.strftime((d1 + td(days=i)))
TypeError: Required argument 'format' (pos 1) not found`

Comment: @StevenGhandi your code has a bad indentation actually i dont have ant idea! can you edit your question with new Erorr?

Comment: No worries all sorted now